# Changing color of selected polygon on google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm using [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) and trying to change the color of an overlaid polygon as it's selected. The polygons are also part of the google-maps-react.

The polygons accept a new selected state, and the setColor function even returns the correct color. It just doesn't change on the map itself.

Code is as follows:

```
setColor = (selected, index) => {
      if (selected) {
          return "blue" //Even when blue is returned, no color change is visible
      } else {
          return "red"
      }
  }



render() {
    return (
        <Polygon
          paths={this.props.paths}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
          strokeColor="#2A2A57"
          strokeOpacity={0.8}
          strokeWeight={2} 
          fillColor = {this.setColor(this.state.isSelected, this.state.index)}
          fillOpacity={0.35}
          {...this.props}
        />
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears *it is by `google-maps-react` library design*, only changing `paths` props [causes `Polygon` to re-render](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/components/Polygon.js#L27).

The following approach could be considered to *update* Polygon properties (e.g, `fillColor`):

1) Get the instance of `Google Maps Polygon` object via [`ref` attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
 <Polygon
          ref={this.polygonRef}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          paths={triangleCoords}
 />
```

2) Update polygon properties via [`Polygon.setOptions` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Polygon.setOptions):

```
handleClick = e =>{
   this.setPolygonOptions({fillColor: "green"});
}
```

where

```
setPolygonOptions = (options) => {
   this.polygonRef.current.polygon.setOptions(options);
};
```

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/k99jxnjn3)

**Update**

Another option would be to access Polygon instance and modify its properties  as demonstrated below. Once the polygon object is clicked, its instance is passed  via the *second* parameter of `click` event:

```
handleClick = (props,polygon,e) => {
    polygon.setOptions({ fillColor: "#ff00ff"});
};
```

[**Demo 2**](https://codesandbox.io/s/v6pnzzq85y)

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer Vadim, this works so I am marking it as solved. However, when I've got multiple polygons it seems like only one of them changes colour. Is there a simple fix for keeping track of multiple polygons? Sorry if it's a stupid question - I'm a complete beginner in react!

Comment: Pastebin of the code if you are interested: https://pastebin.com/7tX9NWHp

Comment: @Matsern, regarding multiple instances of polygons, indeed, keeping track of instances is needed. The second solution (see updated answer) might be a better option to consider

Answer (score 2):

Do this...

```
  <Polygon
      paths={this.props.paths}
      onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
      options={{ strokeOpacity: 0.8, strokeColor: "#2A2A57", fillColor:"#000"}}
      {...this.props}
    />
```

You want to pass the styling options to the Google Maps API via the prop.options.

Comment: I've done as you wrote, and it doesn't seem to change. The polygons get the initial value just fine, but will not change? Could this be a problem elsewhere?

Comment: Okay, if you want the colors to change than your actual options object should be returned upon whatever state change you want to make.  Basically, have your previous function to determine the color to determine the entire object.   I would have that entire options object saved in state, google maps should than re-render for any state changes.